# Firebase (angular) facebook authWithRedirect not working correcting

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, facebook-authentication

I have a login with facebook button using angularfire (Ionic app) and am using $authWithOAuthRedirect to redirect to the facebook authentication page then back to the app.

It works if I have an $onAuth method inside of the function that calls the facebook redirect authentication, but if it's outside of that function it doesn't work. I also have a form for authenticating with email and password and if the $onAuth is inside the facebook authentication method then the email and password login won't work correctly.

Here's the controller that's using the Auth service that is initializing the firebaseAuth:

```
/****
 * Login Page Controller
 * Uses angularfires OAuth for facebook login
****/ 

angular.module('starter')
//inject the Auth service from loginService.js
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth', function($scope, $state, Auth) {

  //userlogin scope variables: error, authData
  $scope.userLogin = {
    error: null
  };


  //Login for email password
  $scope.loginUser = function() {
    Auth.$authWithPassword({
      email: $scope.userLogin.email,
      password: $scope.userLogin.password
    })
    .then(
      function(authData){
        $scope.userLogin.authData = authData;
      }, 
      function(error) {

        if(error.code == 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
          $scope.userLogin.error = "Invalid Email";
        }  
        else if(error.code == 'INVALID_PASSWORD'){
          $scope.userLogin.error = "Email or Password is incorrect";
        } else {
          $scope.userLogin.error = "Enter a valid email and password";
        }

      }
    )
  };

  //login function for facebook login 
  $scope.loginUserFacebook = function() {
    Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect('facebook')
    .then(function(authData) {
      console.log('hi');
    })
    //if error due to no redirects 
    .catch(function(error) {

      //authenticate with popup for emulators
      if (error.code === 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE') {
        Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook').then(function(authData) {
          // console.log(authData);
        });
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }

    });
  };
    //After successful auth
    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      if (authData === null) {
        console.log('Not logged in');
      } 
      else {
         $state.go('driver');
         console.log('Logged in as ' + authData.uid);
      }

      //set authData on controller scope
      $scope.userLogin.authData = authData;
    });

}]);
```

So if I move that Auth.$onAuth up into the loginUserFacebook function then it works, but messes up the loginUser with email and password.

I'm guessing the facebook redirect doesn't resolve a promise like I thought, but I've went through the Firebase docs extensively and can't figure this out.

Comment: Feel free to ping me at rob at firebase dot com if the below answer doesn't get this clarified / resolved for you.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I work at Firebase*

The promise returned from `Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(...)` is a little misleading, because this promise will never be resolved - it can only fail. In cases where you're attempting to use browser redirects on a platform that doesn't support them (PhoneGap, for example) we'll throw a `TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE` error and the promise will be rejected. In all other "successful" cases, the browser will redirect to the OAuth provider and then back to your application, but the prior state of the promise is no longer available.

In order to pick up your authentication session after a successful browser redirect, simply use `Auth.$onAuth(function(authData){...})` to monitor authentication state. On the first return from the OAuth provider, the Firebase client under the hood will complete the creation of the session and raise an event to the callback passed to `onAuth(function(authData){...})` with the current auth state of the user.

Read more about Firebase auth methods [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) and AngularFire's auth tools [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication).